# 88 Level Number

Tags: cobol

```
10  ERROR-FLAG              PIC X VALUE 'N'.
    88  ERROR-FOUND         VALUE 'Y'.      
    88  ERROR-NOT-FOUND     VALUE 'N'.
```

If I do:

```
SET ERROR-NOT-FOUND               TO TRUE
```

Then I do:

```
SET ERROR-FOUND                   TO TRUE
```

Now, what will be the values of ERROR-FLAG, ERROR-FOUND and ERROR-NOT-FOUND?

Comment: For close voters, it is *entirely* clear what is being asked.

Comment: Not that I can answer it, or know any cobol at all... but the question is clear to me also

Comment: In such cases, it is often better to leave ERROR-FLAG as unnamed, or FILLER, so that it can not be referenced directly.  That spares you the trouble of someone coming after you and adding a "MOVE 'a' TO ERROR-FLAG" and totally messing everything up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
10  ERROR-FLAG              PIC X VALUE 'N'.
    88  ERROR-FOUND         VALUE 'Y'.      
    88  ERROR-NOT-FOUND     VALUE 'N'.
```

The 10-level number defines one byte of storage, as alpha-numeric, which means without hint of a problem it can contain any bit-value from X'00' to X'FF'.

The two 88-levels *define no storage*.

An 88 is effectively a way of giving a name to a literal (or some multiple) literal value, but to have it associated only with the particular field that it references (ERROR-FLAG in this case).

Here ERROR-FLAG is the "conditional variable" (which just means it has one or more 88-levels associated with it) and each of the 88s is a "condition-name".

If you do this:

```
SET ERROR-NOT-FOUND                   TO TRUE
```

Then

```
IF ERROR-NOT-FOUND
```

Will be true, and

```
IF ERROR-FOUND
```

Will not be true.

The SET is the same as:

```
MOVE "N"                              TO ERROR-FLAG
```

And the IF is the same as:

```
IF ERROR-FLAG EQUAL TO "N" *> for the IF ERROR-NOT-FOUND
```

The advantages of the 88 and the SET to change the value of the field that it refers to are documentary, and a reduction in maintenance.

Remember, a condition-name defines no storage (strictly, there is storage associated with it, but it just contains a literal and you can't, validly, access it).

So `SET ERROR-NOT-FOUND               TO TRUE` (nice spacing, very nice) does nothing to ERROR-NOT-FOUND (there is nothing that *can* be done), but places the value "N" in ERROR-FLAG.

So `SET ERROR-FOUND                   TO TRUE` does nothing to ERROR-FOUND, but places the value "Y" in ERROR-FLAG.

Coding both those SET statements in sequence simply ends up with ERROR-FLAG being "Y" (the first SET would be redundant).

The SET statement for an 88-level generates code *identical* to a MOVE statement (or should/could, don't know about all compilers). You use the SET so that you can't accidentally mess with the value of a flag through a typo (or through incompetence).

A better structure for flags/switches is:

```
01  FILLER.
    10  FILLER                  PIC X.
        88  ERROR-FOUND         VALUE 'Y'.      
        88  ERROR-NOT-FOUND     VALUE 'N'.
    10  FILLER                  PIC X.
        88  AMOUNT-NUMERIC      VALUE 'Y'.      
        88  AMOUNT-NOT-NUMERIC  VALUE 'N'.
```

When you give the conditional-variable a name, as you did in your example, someone *can* code a `MOVE` to reference it, and typo the value, or make analysis of the code more difficult. Using FILLER to define the fields, which cannot be referenced from the PROCEDURE DIVISION, prevents that happening. The data defined can *only* be accessed through SET and IF (to interrogate the value).

The code would have:

```
SET ERROR-NOT-FOUND     
    AMOUNT-NOT-NUMERIC                TO TRUE
```

To start of each processing iteration (best not to rely on VALUE, as you have to re-set each time anyway) and then individual SET statements when the particular symptoms requiring the flag are identified.

Not, 88's can have multiple values. VALUE "A" "Q" "V" THRU "Z", for example. When doing the SET, the value used is the one mentioned first on the VALUE statement, "A" in this example.

See this answer, with a number of links to other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338755/1927206

Comment: Does it mean that if ERROR-FOUND is set to True, then ERROR-NOT-FOUND will be set to false automatically and vice-versa?

Comment: @Codingman does the update cover this? ERROR-NOT-FOUND is not set to anything. There is no "true" or "false" in COBOL, except in the SET (and FALSE is beyond the 1985 Standard). If it is still unclear, let me know.